# Обработка нажатия клавиш Turbo Pascal

Tags: pascal

Не могу придумать, как реализовать обработку нажатия клавиши в цикле repeat until на паскале.

Требуется, чтобы цикл выполнялся постоянно и выход из него происходил по нажатию клавиши.

Программа должна спросить у пользователя, как он хочет получить результат (нажмите 1 для выполнения по программе 1 или 2 для выполнения по программе 2)

После окончания выполнения программа должна спросить у пользователя, хочет он выйти или продолжить выполнения программы (нажмите 3 для выхода или 4 для продолжения выполнения)

Пробовал через readkey

```
var 
  key:char;
begin
  repeat
    if keypressed then
    begin
      key := readkey;
      case key of
        #27 : exit;
        #13 : {вставил программу 1};
        #8  : {вставил программу 2};    
      end;
    end;
  until key = #27
end.
```

Turbo Pascal 7.0; Операционная система - MS DOS

Answer (score -1):

[ReadKey](http://pascal.net.ru/ReadKey)

**С помощью цикла** `while do`:

```
program keyreader;

uses crt;

procedure program1;
begin
    writeln('Выполнена программа 1');
end;

procedure program2;
begin
    writeln('Выполнена программа 2' + #13);
end;

var
    key: char;

begin
    writeln('Для выполнения программы 1 нажмите <Enter>,');
    writeln('Для выполнения программы 2 нажмите <Backspace>,');
    writeln('Для выхода нажмите <Ctrl + [>...');
    writeln();
    writeln('Как Вы хотите получить результат?');

    while true do       
        begin
            key := ReadKey;

            case key of
                #27,
                #110 : exit;
                #13  : program1;
                #8   : program2;
                #121 : 
                    begin
                        writeln();
                        writeln('Как Вы хотите получить результат?');
                        continue;
                    end;
            else
                writeln('Такой программы не найдено!');
            end;

            writeln('Хотите продолжить? Yes - <y>, No - <n>...');
        end;
end.
```

**С помощью цикла** `repeat until`:

```
program keyreader;

uses crt;

procedure program1;
begin
    writeln('Выполнена программа 1');
    writeln('Хотите продолжить? Yes - <y>, No - <n>...');
end;

procedure program2;
begin
    writeln('Выполнена программа 2' + #13);
    writeln('Хотите продолжить? Yes - <y>, No - <n>...');
end;

var
    key: char;

begin
    writeln('Для выполнения программы 1 нажмите <Enter>,');
    writeln('Для выполнения программы 2 нажмите <Backspace>,');
    writeln('Для выхода нажмите <Ctrl + [>...');
    writeln();
    writeln('Как Вы хотите получить результат?');

    repeat      
        begin
            key := ReadKey;

            case key of
                #27  : writeln('Выход...');
                #110 : exit;
                #13  : program1;
                #8   : program2;
                #121 : 
                    begin
                        writeln();
                        writeln('Как Вы хотите получить результат?');
                    end;
            else
                begin
                    writeln('Такой программы не найдено!');
                    writeln('Хотите продолжить? Yes - <y>, No - <n>...');
                end;
            end;
        end;
    until key = #27
end.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь

Comment: И я хотел спросить, почему нужно оставить в case одну команду пустым?Если убрать, то выдает, что нужно end 

#8   : program2;

                #121 :

Comment: Я написал программу без (    writeln('Для выполнения программы 1 нажмите <Enter>,');
    writeln('Для выполнения программы 2 нажмите <Backspace>,');
    writeln('Для выхода нажмите <Ctrl + [>...');
    writeln();
    writeln('Как Вы хотите получить результат?');)
Вставил вместо ваших свои программы, и они работают, если только одну пустую команду оставлю в case of key

Comment: @АндрейКлючевский `#27, #110 : exit;` это не пустая команда, `exit` сработает при обоих вариантах

Comment: а команда  **#121:**  почему пуста? У меня при выполнения, если убрать ее и заменить на **end;**, то программа начинает придираться к **else**. Мы не находим общий язык(требует убрать ; после end, a потом пишет, что нужна ; и т.д.)

Comment: @АндрейКлючевский нет там пустых команд, просто для читаемости `begin ... end` перенес на новую строку

Comment: Понял, спасибо за объяснения